# Stepped Report for Recursive data in RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have one requirement in which we need to show data in the form of parent, child, grand-child upto multiple levels. saw some blogs but couldn't find any specific solution for that.

data should be shown like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link below, It might help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14445/Reporting-Hierarchical-Recursive-Data-using-MS-Rep

Comment: Hey prashant thanks but example is looking for Old visual studio version. might be it could have change now.